# Frankfurt Airport Side Transit

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, fra

Need to check if Indian Passport holder have USED/EXPIRED UK Visa and travelling on below routing, does he require airport side transit visa at FRA

DEL -x FRA -x PTY - POS

Note : Connecting flight from FRA to PTY will be within 12hrs

Answer (score 0):

Inputting this data into Timatic yields these teduktsmfor Germany:

> **Transiting without a visa is possible for:**
>
> Nationals of India transiting through Frankfurt (FRA) or Munich (MUC), arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 24 hours to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United Kingdom, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for their next destination.

As your UK visa is expired this doesn’t apply.

The transit information for Panama is:

> **Visa not required**